# Linux OpenWRT microphone streaming with commandline

Tags: linux, command-line, streaming, audio-streaming, openwrt

i would like to stream the microphone input of my Linux OpenWRT-device over the network. The soundcard is already working. Is there any simple way to stream the microphone input over the network (without compression is ok ...)?

Answer (score 0):

SSH in and get the raw audio data via `arecord`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way without arecord?

Comment: Yes. Use some other app that understands ALSA.